# Powershell Search

Tags: powershell, output

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Search my computer for files ending with a .doc, .docx, .xls, or .xlsx
2. Output the filenames and sizes (in groups by file extension) to a text file named “File_Summary.txt”.
3. I also want the total of the number of files and total file size for each file extension listed in the output.

I can't even get past the check folder part:

```
$Folder_To_Check = C:\AIU

$Report_File_Location = "File_Summary.txt"

$files= Get-Childitem -Path $Folder_To_Check-Include *doc, *docx, *xls, *xlsx $Report_File_Location
$totalfiles = ($files | Measure-Object).Count
$totalsize = ($files | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
```

**Update. Here is my code again with some changes I made from the suggestions, but I'm still coming up empty.**

```
$Report_File_Location = "File_Summary.txt"

$files= Get-Childitem C:\AIU -include "*doc", "*docx", "*xls", "*xlsx"-recurse | Sort-Object | Get-Unique -asString

$files | Out-File $Report_File_Location

$totalfiles = ($files | Measure-Object).Count
$totalsize = ($files | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum 

write-host "totalfiles: $totalfiles"
write-host "totalsize: $totalsize"
```

The more I was looking about this I think I shouldn't use the `Sort-Object` but to use `Group Extension -NoElement | Sort Count -Descending` that would give me the total number of files for each type?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to help of people here I got my code to work. But I had an issue where it was saying that my file didn't exist. The problem? I needed to list the entire folder path and use SINGLE quotes.

This code works:

```
$Folder_To_Check = 'C:\Users\Sarah\Documents\AIU'
$Report_File_Location = "File_Summary.txt"

$results = Get-ChildItem $Folder_To_Check -Include *.doc,*.docx,*.xls,*.xlsx -Recurse
$results | Group-Object extension | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Results = $_.Name
        Count = $_.Count
        Size = [Math]::Round(($_.Group | Measure-Object -Sum Length | Select-Object -    ExpandProperty Sum) / 1MB,2)
    }
} | Out-File $Report_File_Location -Append
```

**BIG props to Matt for helping me organize my results so nice. Thank you for helping me learn.**

Comment: One of the edits in my answer broke my code. I restored it to working order if you want to try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Folder_To_Check = C:\AIU
$Report_File_Location = "File_Summary.txt"

$results = Get-ChildItem $Folder_To_Check -Include *.doc,*.docx,*.xls,*.xlsx -Recurse 
$results | Group-Object extension | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Extension = $_.Name
        Count = $_.Count
        Size = [Math]::Round(($_.Group | Measure-Object -Sum Length | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum) / 1MB,2)
    }
} | Out-File $Report_File_Location -Append
```

Get all of the files you are looking for with `Get-ChildItem` much like you were. Vasja mentioned it as well that you might want to use `-Recurse` to get results from sub directories as well. Use `Group-Object` to collect the files by extension. For each collection output a custom object of the extension and file count, which both come `Group-Object`, and the size of all the files of that particular extension converted to MB and rounded to 2 decimal places.

**Update for 2.0**

In case you only have 2.0 installed I wanted to provide and answer that works for that.

```
$results | Group-Object extension | ForEach-Object {
    $properties = @{
        Extension = $_.Name
        Count = $_.Count
        Size = [Math]::Round(($_.Group | Measure-Object -Sum Length | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum) / 1MB,2)
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties
}
```

Comment: Im an idiot and deleted the `Get-ChildItem` call in my answer in one of my edits.

Comment: @AnemonePoppy please try my code again. If it does not work have a look at the 2.0 answer in cause you only have 2.0.

Comment: @Matt. I marked your answer as the correct one because it was the most helpful. I'm still having issues as PS says my C:file doesn't exist, and I don't know what to do about that; but at least the Recurse is working.

Comment: @AnemonePoppy I dont recall you mentioning this issue anywhere. You could update your question or start a new one?

Comment: @Matt I figured it out and I knew it was something so dumb and small. I needed to list the entire path and use single quotes. Fiddling with it finally gave me the results I wanted. Shout-out to all your help in the latest update :)

Answer (score 2):

Added some quotes.
Also you probably want `-Recurse` on `Get-Childitem`

```
$Folder_To_Check = "C:\AIU"
$Report_File_Location = "E:\tmp\File_Summary.txt"
$files = Get-Childitem -Path $Folder_To_Check -Include *doc, *docx, *xls, *xlsx -Recurse

$files | Out-File $Report_File_Location

$totalfiles = ($files | Measure-Object).Count
$totalsize = ($files | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

write-host "totalfiles: $totalfiles"
write-host "totalsize: $totalsize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you need a collection of strings for the -Include argument. So, what you tried is one string, that being:

```
"*doc, *docx, *xls, *xlsx"
```

While the commas do need to seperate the extensions when you include it within the quotes it thinks that's a part of the one thing to include, so it's seriously looking for files that have anything (as per the asterisk) then "doc," then anything then "docx," then anything then... you see where I'm going. It thinks it has to include all of that. Instead you need a collection of strings like:

```
-Include "*doc","*docx","*xls","xlsx"
```

I hope that helps. Here's your line modified to what should work:

```
$files= Get-Childitem -Path $Folder_To_Check-Include "*doc", "*docx", "*xls", "*xlsx"
```

Comment: While your point is valid I didnt see quotes around her original `-Include`? Seems valid as per [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee176841.aspx)

Comment: Right you are, she didn't have them, but did say that she had tried it with quotes around the entire thing. Depending on her PS version I think the older versions would parse the whole thing as a string when sending it to the provider unless you were fairly explicit on how you structured it. Personally I hate the FileSytem Provider's parsing engine and usually try to filter afterwards in PS with a Where clause unless it's taking super long.

Comment: The parsing engine is terrible.